# Is there any other way to do google authentication or using passport is the best way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm new to node and passport, i wanted to know that is there any other way to do google and facebook authentication for backend or using passport is the best solution. Also what is difference between "npm install passport" and "npm install passport-local".

Answer (score 0):

Ofc there are (depends what you want to do).

**what is difference between "npm install passport" and "npm install passport-local"**

In simple termns:

"passport-local" is the server. Allows you to provide keys for other passport strategies.
"passport" is the client. Thats what you need.